# Lightweight implementation of promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I am building a simple charting tool. When a user chooses a data source and a chart type, both the data and the script for the specific chart (.js) are loaded and then the code renders the chart.

Currently I use the following sequence:

1. Load the chart script
2. Load the data
3. Render the chart

To improve performance, I'd like to implement promises and load script and data in parallel. A library like jQuery is too big for my needs (the point of the question is not to argue on this), are there more lightweight solutions? Maybe a 1-2 kb library, or a tutorial? Again, this is a very basic implementation with just two actions in parallel.

[Update] I upvoted all the replies as they all look excellent. I'll report back after I do some more testing.

Comment: Do you want to know only and specifically about promises? Or do you want to know any methods than can improve parallelism? If the latter please clarify the wording.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I built something like this a while back that I called "when-then". I wanted something that would say, "Load all of these things, then do something when they're done".

https://github.com/geuis/when-then

I was inspired by the promises idea, but wanted something a little simpler for simple tasks.

Comment: thx. I checked out your code but didn't see how to check when a script has finished loading on the page (cf. step 1 in my sequence).

Comment: You don't need to check using when-then. Basically, its setup so all you have to do is when(function1, function2, function3).then(function(){ //func1-3 are done here}); Look at the examples on the page. =)

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. I need to load the functions, not to execute them. For example: when (jQuery is loaded and data.json is loaded) then (run code that depends on jQuery and uses data.json).

Comment: Marking this one as answer because it addresses my specific need of a lightweight library.

Answer (score 13):

I strongly suggest using an implementation of the [Promises/A specification](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A), which is becoming the standard way of doing promises in JavaScript. Promises work better when everyone uses the same flavor, so it's in everyone's interest to use compatible implementations.

[Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) is probably the most popular and fully featured implementation (it also will adapt jQuery and other incompatible promises), while [when](https://github.com/cujojs/when) and [rsvp](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js) are supposed to be more "lightweight".

Comment: This makes sense, but I find the specification too vague to be really useful. For example whether jQuery adheres to it is not clear. Also, it doesn't really tell how the returned object (status and result) is structured, so in practice you see different flavors.

Comment: We now have a draft of the standard, and apparently it is based on the promises/A+ specification.

Answer (score 7):

Wanted to throw in my 2¢ as there's been a development here. [Promises have arrived natively in JavaScript](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) and will be implemented for FF 30 and Chrome 33 (according to [this table](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/)).

Although that's hardly worth mentioning in a place that's usually flooded with "but does it support IE6?", there's a 2kb minified and gzipped polyfill [here](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise#readme) that is "basically an API remapping of [rsvp.js](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js)."

Since jQuery promises [aren't really promises](http://domenic.me/2012/10/14/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/), and I agree with [this guy](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2013/09/20/consistency-problems-with-apis-in-javascript-promise-libraries/) that promise syntax is inconsistent across libraries, my view is that native promises are already worth implementing even though your users' browsers probably don't support them yet.

---

Edit: After using Promises in the context of Angular and the Firefox addon-SDK, both of which are very similar to [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), I prefer that syntax and have read that it is still faster than the native implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Check [Deferred](https://github.com/medikoo/deferred) it has modular build, and you can decide just to take core and that shouldn't be larger than 1kb.

[Browser install instructions](https://github.com/medikoo/deferred#browser) explains how to create such bundle in few easy steps

Answer (score 2):

If you want it really lightweight, You should try [sb-promise](https://github.com/steelbrain/promise), It's under MIT license. It's just a few kbs and is API compatible with native Promises.

```
function myFunction(){
   return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
     resolve({some:"data"});
   }
}
myFunction().then(function(result){
   console.log(result); // {some:"data"}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

It has methods to do operations in parallel, and in series. It was originally designed to run in node, but now works in browser as well.

EDIT TO ADD: They don't have a minified version, so the full enchilada is ~42kb.

Comment: Async does not implement promises at all. It uses an unrelated paradigm known as "continuation passing".

Comment: True, however, async does allow for "parallel" execution of functions, which is what the OP wanted (promises are just one way to achieve this).

Comment: @hippietrail mea culpa, I really meant concurrent load. Futures/deferreds/promises are the most common pattern and I didn't even consider that there could be other ways.

Answer (score 0):

I created a very lightweight promise library. It is not A compliant, but i did not want something 2,000 lines long.

It is a fork of promisejs, but I made some nice additions.

Here is a link to the repo.
https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-light