# merge response of two parallel ajax call using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to do two ajax call parallel and in response will get two array from each call. I want to merge those two array and display in HTML. What is the best way to do it. How will we get to know that both call is completed or any one call is disrupted. A callback should get fired only if both ajax call is completed successfully

Comment: "best way"; please explain what that means objectively Also, please show some code; SO is not a code-writing service. Currently this question is quite broad.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I have answered it using promise. But promise is not supported in all browser. So can we do it any other way.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried before. Otherwise you are going to get a bunch of guesses, as shown below.

Comment: Edited @MikeMcCaughan Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do the merge:

```
var result1 = ['a', 'b'];
var result2 = ['c', 'd'];
var mergedResult = result1.concat(result2);
```

**EDIT**

In the meantime, you told us, that you don't want an array merge, but synchronized ajax calls. I see a few solutions for that:

1. If you don't need to support **all** browsers, use promises, see http://caniuse.com/#search=promise
2. If you need to support older browsers, I would recommend a library. Maybe you already use jQuery, or you could look at [Lightweight implementation of promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923533/lightweight-implementation-of-promises) to see some more lightweight libraries.
3. You could try a 'small' solution by counting open ajax calls, decrease the counter when one of them completes and do your action after the counter reaches zero again. I would not recommend that, but it's the easy way.

Comment: I need to merge response to two ajax call that executes parallel

Comment: Nope! My concern is to achieve above result with core JS without using any libraries. I ll have two XHR object which will run parallel and a single function should get executed once tow XHR response status is 200. This is my exact query.

Comment: Ok, if you want older browsers to work as well (which are excluded by the first variant) you need to use a counter (like described in variant 3).

Answer (score 0):

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
//Ajax call 1
resolve(response1)
})
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
//Ajax call 2
resolve(response2)
})

Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(function(values){
//Here we will get values of p1, p2
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!